# Where did System.Design go?

Tags: c#, .net, scintilla

I am making a C# project in which I am using ScintillaNet, and it says:

> The referenced assembly "ScintillaNet" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your project.

I tried adding a reference to `System.Design`, but it doesn't exist in my list. Do I need to download it somewhere? I have Microsoft Visual Studio 10.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Go to the project's properties and select the target framework to be .NET 4.0, not Client Profile

Comment: Yes, that worked. But no explanation. Not even a link.

Comment: A wrong edit was made by @bvoyelr which should be here in the comments : [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912(v=vs.110).aspx) says that the client profile existed in all version of .NET prior to 4.5, but I have only ever seen the option in visual studio for .net 4.0