# Problems when adding custom control dll into my Form(WinForm)

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

Adding the custom control from my toolbox into a form works fine, however when I try to build the project I'm getting this error; "The type or namespace name "CustomControls" could not be found", but
when I check the project's "References", I can see the CustomControls located at the very top.

Comment: Check that the .Net version of your CustomControls assembly matches (or is compatible with) the target .Net version of your project.

Comment: hmm. I'm also getting that warning Warning The referenced assembly "CustomControls" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your project. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets 1360

Comment: yep, that's the problem right there.  re-target your project to full 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your project to target the full version of .Net 4.0 (not the client profile).

Answer (score 0):

Also check that the custom control DLL is not platform x86 only, while you are using 'Any CPU', I once had some  weird errors because of this.
As for the warning you get, the following might solve your problem [Where did System.Design go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030484/where-did-system-design-go)